# Nginx wordpress and its wrong path

Tags: path, nginx, url, wordpress

I've a Raspberry and I installed **nginx** and over this I put **Wordpress**.

Wordpress installation come from an old backup of a websites that I hosted somewhere else. The URL was **mydomain.com/home**, now in the nginx's root I created the directory *mydomain.com* and inside another directory called *home*

> ../mydomain.com/home

Inside home are located all wordpress files.

When I type in the browser mydomain.com, it load an empty page (www.mydomain.com/home/). If I add wp-login.php I can access to the admin panel doing everything, but if I try to show published either posts or pages I get 
**error 404**.

**/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # nginx-naxsi config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

    ##
    # nginx-passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
    ##

    #passenger_root /usr;
    #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    index index.php index.html;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

**/etc/nginx/conf.d/mydomain.conf**

```
server {
  server_name www.mydomain.com mydomain.com; 
  root /usr/share/nginx/www/mydomain.com;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/mydomain.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/mydomain.error.log;

location / {
        autoindex on;
        autoindex_exact_size off;
}
# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    #   # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
    #
    #   # With php5-cgi alone:
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php5-fpm:
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

Comment: Going to need to see Nginx config file to debug this more.

Comment: I've added nginx and domain configuration files